# React Component Props typed with two Omit<...> | Omit<....> throwing TS error 2339. Property x does not exist on Pick | Pick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Example of the problem. I have a component that takes the following props:

```
interface OwnProps {
    text: string;
    tKey: string; 
    color: string;
    height: number; 
}
```

I want the component to accept these props, but enforce that you can only pass in either the text prop or the tKey prop, but not both. So I wrote it like so:

```
interface Props {
    text: string;
    tKey: string; 
    color: string;
    height: number; 
}

type OwnProps = Omit<Props, 'text'> | Omit<Props, 'tKey'>;

const Component = ({text, tKey, color, height}: Props) {
....
}
```

OwnProps type seems right. However within the component when I am de-structuring the props typescript throws a ts-2339 error. When I do a similar set up using interfaces like:

```
interface BaseProps {
    color: string;
    height: number;
}

interface PropsText extends BaseProps {
    text: string;
    tKey?: never;
}

interface PropsTKey extends BaseProps {
    tKey: string;
    text?: never;
}
```

Typescript is fine with that. I am wondering if there is something about the Omit, or the type that typescript is not happy about. Ideally finding a solution where you can use the Omit would be great.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The examples you gave are not equivalent:

- Omit removes the property completely, so types which omit a different property have different set of properties.
- Your interfaces both have same set of properties.

To make an union of exclusive options, modify your OwnProps:

```
type OwnProps = (Omit<Props, 'text'> & {text?: never}) | (Omit<Props, 'tKey'> & {tKey?: never});

const Component = ({text, tKey, color, height}: OwnProps) => {
  // return ...
}
```

Comment: Aaah. That makes sense. Thanks so much for the response!